# setState is not updating the state even callback

Tags: reactjs

On input field change, the handler function gets called and updates the state, but the state is not getting updated. I know `setState()` is async so I put the `console.log` in the callback.

Here are the functions:

```js
class WorkspaceEditModal extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(props.selectedWorkspace); // prints correct value
    this.state = {
      editWorkspaceName: props.selectedWorkspace,
      exists: false,
    };
  }

  handleEditChange = event => { // this handler is called
    console.log(event.target.value); // prints new value
    this.setState({ editWorkspaceName: event.target.value },
      () => {console.log(this.state.editWorkspaceName)}); // still prints old value
  };

  handleFocus = e => e.target.select();

  handleKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.editWorkspace();
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { editWorkspaceName, exists } = this.state;
    let content;

    content = (
        <div className="save-workspace">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <div className="modal-title">
              <p>Rename Workspace</p>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-select">
              <span className="input-label">Workspace Name</span>
              <div>
                <input
                  className="name-input"
                  placeholder="Workspace Name"
                  type="text"
                  defaultValue={editWorkspaceName}
                  onChange={this.handleEditChange} // calls the handler on change
                  onFocus={this.handleFocus}
                  onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
                  autoFocus
                />
                {notValid && (
                  <p className="invalid">
                    Only alphanumeric characters, hyphens, spaces, and
                    underscores are allowed.
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-default"
              onClick={this.onCloseModal}
            >
              Cancel
            </button>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={this.editWorkspace}
              disabled={notValid}
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );

    const contentStyle = {
      width: '500px',
    };

    return (
      <Modal
        isOpen={true}
        onClose={this.onCloseModal}
        contentStyle={contentStyle}
        shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
      >
        {content}
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know why this is happening. This is crazy.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, @1housand, I have tested with your code and it works. i think you have got wrong with another side. look this [result](https://prnt.sc/pvn237)

Comment: Hi, @DragonWhite, thanks for the reply. i didn't write this code, but the weirdest thing is that there's another modal component where the code is very similar and it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

You are passing down the default value of the input via props. That should be your input default value. It should not update the state of the child component.

State should be updated on the parent component, not the child in this case. The handleEditChange (handleChange in example) function should be placed in the parent component, then passed down via props to the input. You want the props value changed in the parent via that parent function so that setState works properly.

You could use getDerivedStateFromProps, but it seems unnecessary here. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

```
class ParentWorkSpaceEditModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      editWorkspaceName: 'whatever your original value is',
      exists: false,
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ editWorkspaceName: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { editWorkspaceName, exists } = this.state;
    return (
      <ChildWorkspaceEditModal editWorkspaceName={editWorkspaceName} exists={exists} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
    )
  }
}

const ChildWorkspaceEditModal = ({ editWorkspaceName, exists, handleChange )} => {
  content = (
    <div className="save-workspace">
      <div className="modal-header">
        <div className="modal-title">
          <p>Rename Workspace</p>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-select">
          <span className="input-label">Workspace Name</span>
          <div>
            <input
              className="name-input"
              placeholder="Workspace Name"
              type="text"
              value={editWorkspaceName}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            {notValid && (
              <p className="invalid">
              Only alphanumeric characters, hyphens, spaces, and underscores are allowed.
              </p>
             )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-default"
          onClick={this.onCloseModal}
        >
          Cancel
         </button>
         <button
           type="button"
           className="btn btn-primary"
           onClick={this.editWorkspace}
           disabled={notValid}
         >
          Update
         </button>
       </div>
     </div>
  );

  const contentStyle = {
    width: '500px',
  };

  return (
      <Modal
        isOpen={true}
        onClose={this.onCloseModal}
        contentStyle={contentStyle}
        shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
      >
        {content}
      </Modal>
    )
}
```

Comment: Ofc it's okey to use 'props' in constructor since 'props' in constructor is actually the same thing as 'this.props'. And about the argument that 'state should be updated in parent' - why? Can't agree with that.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html - state should not be updated from props. Props are intended to be used directly. If props are intended to change, they should be changed from the parent component where they were updated.

Comment: It's better if state is independent from props, however it's an often case that state depends on it. For that purpose e.g. 'getDeriviedStateFromProps' lifecycle hook was created. I see nothing wrong in setting **initial** state from props.

Comment: Looking at the ReactJS documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops.  it specifically says: "Note
Avoid copying props into state! This is a common mistake" I've always followed this rule after having similar problems and avoiding setting state with props has solved it for me. The getDeriviedStateFromProps lifecycle will work, but it just seemed unnecessary for a simple input.

Comment: Here's one more page to checkout for reference: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: Sure, but in this particular case we dont really care about props updating, we just set the **initial** value for state. From now on we dont care about props or parent. From now on we will only use state to change data in our component

Comment: It is a common mistake, agreed, but in other case - when people rely on that props but they dont use it directly (e.g. color={this.props.color}), but saving it to state, so the component wont re-render if props changed.